# Compare strings of a column in a dataframe with a set of words in a list

Tags: python, pandas, compare, tweets

I have a dataframe with a single column `full_text` containing tweets and there is a list `negative` containing negative words. I want to create a new column that returns a boolean value if the negative words are found in the tweets as `1` and `0` if not found.

Comment: I want to extract a parent dataframe of tweets, 2 sets of positive and negative tweets based on the list `negative` containing negative words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's assume we have a dataframe `data` and list `negative_words` like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tweets' : ['This is bad', 'This is terrible', 'This is good', 'This is great'],
})

negative_words = ['bad', 'terrible']
```

We can then do something like:

1) We can use a `lambda` function with `any`:

```
# create lambda with any:
data['Negative'] = data.apply(lambda x: True if any(word in x.Tweets for word in negative_words) else False, axis=1)
```

And will get:

```
             Tweets  Negative
0       This is bad      True
1  This is terrible      True
2      This is good     False
3     This is great     False
```

Comment: thanks! that seems robust. But can we reduce it two just 1 line of code

Comment: Can we use the lambda function if 'Tweets` is a list instead of dataframe?

Comment: `text4b = list(filter(lambda x: negative in x, text))` It gives error. Can somebody help?

Comment: `text` is the list of tweets containing more than 50,000 tweets.

Comment: You can do: `data = pd.DataFrame({'Tweets' : ['tweet1', 'tweet2' ...]})` to convert the list to a dataframe

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get that. But, can we get the iteration over list in my code right. It's giving error.

Comment: something like `text4b = list(filter(lambda x: (for word in negative for word in x), text)) `

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Daniel, Im working with something similar but hashes, How could I remove the words from the columns Tweets, instead of returning True/False?